# Finding the MAX values from a group by of a Joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to resolve the following.

I have two tables looking at membership within different stores and customers who have membership with these stores and how much points they had saved up. Each customer may be a member to multiple stores and their membership points for these stores varies. Both tables are linked by the personID.
I currently have a code set up that takes the name of the stores from table a, the name of the customer from table b and the sum of the points the customer has from column b.
So it looks something like this:

```
SELECT A.storename, B.lastname, SUM(B.memberpoints) AS 'memberpoints'
FROM
Storetable AS A
JOIN
Customertable AS B
ON
A.personID = B.personID
GROUP BY A.storename,B.lastname
ORDER BY memberpoints DESC
```

What I got was a table that shows me a list of the stores with the customers and for each of them the one with the most amount of points for that customer for that store.
So something like this:

| storename | lastname | memberpoints |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ASDA | Smith | 8000 |
| ASDA | Henry | 6500 |
| Tesco | Johns | 6450 |
| Tesco | Smith | 6230 |
| ASDA | Gregs | 6220 |
| M&S | Jacobs | 6000 |
| M&S | Abdul | 5550 |
| Tesco | Gregs | 5000 |

What I have been trying to do is only show each store's member that has the most points whilst omitting the rest so for example for ASDA only Smith will be shown, for Tesco only Johns etc I have been trying to see how I can use the MAX function or a subquery but it has not worked thus far.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3) I also recommend against single quotes (`'`) for aliases. They only work when you define them, no where else (`ORDER BY `'memberpoints'` won't work as you think) and some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Comment: also add all tables and data as text to your code, but a Rwo_NUMBER should work just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the window function `ROW_NUMBER` for that, but you need also a CTE to select the customer with the highest number

It will not get you multiple customer with the higHest poInts, for that you need `RANK` or `DENSE_RAnk`

> ```
> WITH CTE AS 
> (SELECT St.storename, Cu.lastname, SUM(Cu.memberpoints) AS [memberpoints]
> , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY St.storename ORDER BY SUM(Cu.memberpoints) DESC) rn
> FROM
> Storetable AS St
> JOIN
> Customertable AS Cu
> ON
> St.personID = Cu.personID
> GROUP BY St.storename,Cu.lastname)
> SELECT storename,lastname,memberpoints FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
> ```

> ```
> storename | lastname | memberpoints
> :-------- | :------- | -----------:
> ASDA      | Smith    |         8000
> M&S       | Jacobs   |         6000
> Tesco     | Smith    |         8000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4c30a80152246ae3f293bab7f5c16d0a)*